# Many: `require': cannot load such file -- "gem_name" (LoadError) after upgrade of ruby/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, upgrade

After I just upgrade rails from 4.1 and ruby from 2.0 to 2.1 I'm getting several load issues when I try to start rails. Many of my gems are throwing errors like this:

```
/Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require': cannot load such file -- jwt (LoadError)
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/oauth2-1.0.0/lib/oauth2/strategy/assertion.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/oauth2-1.0.0/lib/oauth2.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/omniauth-oauth2-1.2.0/lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/omniauth-facebook-2.0.0/lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/omniauth-facebook-2.0.0/lib/omniauth/facebook.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/omniauth-facebook-2.0.0/lib/omniauth-facebook.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
  from /Users/nk/Programmering/au/au/config/application.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:146:in `require'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:146:in `require_application_and_environment!'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  from script/rails:6:in `require'
  from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

My gem file looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Rake and rails
gem 'rake', '10.3.2'
gem 'rails', '4.1.6'

gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'rails-observers'
gem 'actionpack-page_caching'
gem 'actionpack-action_caching'
gem 'activerecord-deprecated_finders'


# Databases and caching
gem 'pg', '0.17.1'
gem 'apartment', '0.25.2'
gem 'redis', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'foreigner', '1.6.1'
gem 'geocoder', '1.2.5'
gem 'dalli', '2.7.2'
gem 'hstore_accessor', '~> 0.6.0'

# Files and processing
gem 'fog', '~> 1.24.0'
gem 'rmagick', '~> 2.13.2', require: 'RMagick'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.10.0'
gem 'carrierwave-meta', '~> 0.0.5'
gem 'rubyzip', '~> 1.1.2'
gem 'sitemap_generator', '~> 5.0.1'
gem 'rubyXL', '~> 3.2.3'

# Model layer
gem 'squeel', '~> 1.2.1'
gem 'ransack', '~> 1.4.0'
gem 'state_machine', '~> 1.2.0'
gem 'active_attr', '0.8.4'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '2.0.0'
gem 'omniauth-identity', '1.1.1'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2', require: 'bcrypt'
gem 'redis-objects', '~> 1.0.0'
gem 'leaderboard', '~> 3.7.0'
```

Now if I then comment out `omniauth-facebook` then i just get the following for `bcrupt` instead:

```
/Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require': cannot load such file -- bcrypt (LoadError)
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
  from /Users/nk/Programmering/au/au/config/application.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:146:in `require'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:146:in `require_application_and_environment!'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
  from /Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@au_rails4/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  from script/rails:6:in `require'
  from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

And it just continues like that. Why are some of my gems suddenly causing this?

Comment: Can you please also post your `Gemfile.lock`?

Comment: Might be really far off here, but in case you are using Spring or something pre-loady like that (which is, I believe is included within Rails 4 now), I have seen some very similar errors that i could solve with "spring stop", just give it a shot ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There must be some problem in your local ruby installation.

If you are using rvm gemset then run `rvm pristine` on your gemset.
If you are not using gemset then run `gem pristine --all`

Comment: Newer versions of rvm now use `rvm reinstall`, which "reinstalls ruby and runs gem pristine on all gems"

Comment: THANK YOU. I've been dealing with an issue for days now. Running `gem pristine --all` fixed it. Well, and installing `ruby-devel`. So relieved.

Answer (score 4):

To me it feels like you had some gems install globally without bundler and without adding that gems to your `Gemfile`. Without your `Gemfile.lock` it is hard to tell, but the `jwt` Gem for example is not in your `Gemfile`.

I would try to add the missing gems to your Gemfile, run `bundle install` again.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reinstalling gems with bundler to location within your application?

```
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

Also: if this didn't help, I would try to removing gemset within rvm and try bundle / rails c again.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I hope you're running "bundle exec rails c" and not just "rails c" to ensure you load gems from the correct places.

if that is the case, Try running "bundle show bcrypt" and check the path, it should start with

```
"/Users/nk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/"
```

If  it doesn't, resetting bundler by deleting Gemfile.lock and running bundle install again or similar might help.

Answer (score 0):

did you run`bundle update` after migrating? If not please run `bundle update` and try. Before doing this remove Gemfile.lock file

Comment: I did, it runs fine. No problem at all. The issue occurs when I try to run `rails console` afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Delete your **Gemfile.lock** file and try to run **bundle update** and then **bundle install** again. I hope it works for you.