# Ruby on rails stripe gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

Im trying to use stripe checkout. I have added gem 'stripe' in my gemfile and ive run bundle install. However, when I try starting my server again I get this error.

Ive tried looking through the docs and theres nothing on this error.

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
42: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
41: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
40: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
39: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
38: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
37: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
36: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
35: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
34: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
33: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
32: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
31: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
30: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
29: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
28: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
27: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
26: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
25: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `block in perform'
24: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
23: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
22: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
21: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
20: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
19: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
18: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
17: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
16: from /Users/kevinlopez/Desktop/rlab/rails/teamcarer/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
15: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
14: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
13: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
12: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
11: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
10: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
 9: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
 8: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
 7: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
 6: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
 5: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
 4: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/stripe-4.9.0/lib/stripe.rb:6:in `<main>'
 3: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
 2: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
 1: from /Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
/Users/kevinlopez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require': cannot load such file -- faraday (LoadError)
```

Im expecting to start my server so i can start building my controllers and views for payment but i am receiving this error. Would anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26465459/9418609

Comment: didnt work im still gettin the same error

Comment: Is `faraday` in your `Gemfile`?

Comment: @tadman no its not

Comment: is it required to use stripe?

Comment: may be there is dependency on `faraday`

Answer (score 0):

That error's indicating, on the last line, that the `faraday` dependency isn't being met. It's worth adding:

```
gem 'faraday'
```

To your `Gemfile` and then adding with `bundle install`.

Normally gems declare their own dependencies so they get loaded automatically, but in some cases that's not practical.

Comment: hmm... ive added this ran bundle install but still return same error when i try starting up the server

Comment: faraday was successfully installed as well

Comment: Does a quick script in that directory with `require 'bundler/setup'` and `require 'faraday'` produce the same error?

Comment: could this be a stripe bug?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it, more likely it's your Ruby is not able to find the `faraday` dependency even though in that quick test it could. I'd try and reproduce it on another Rails project, even one created specifically for this test. It could be that the Rails "bootsnap"/[Spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) thing is confused about dependencies, so try `bin/spring stop` to see if that resets it.

Comment: it said spring is currently not running

Comment: i think theres a problem with my ruby not being able to ready it